# How to figure out which version of Rust an RFC or a feature was stabilized

Tags: rust, rfc

I am trying to figure out an easy way, if it exists, to look at a particular RFC or a PR and figure out which version of Rust it was stabilized in.

I do not want to parse the releases/tags section for information. It could get difficult if it is an older release.

I know if it is a function or API, the docs usually have a tag indicating when it was stable, like `#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]`.

But what if it is a language feature/improvement like for example [De-structuring assignments (RFC#2909)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2909).

This one was stabilized in 1.59.0 but I'd like a straightforward method of figuring it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the RFC page you linked, there is a link for the corresponding [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71126), which includes a link to the corresponding [stabilization PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/90521), where you can see the corresponding [milestone](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/milestone/89).